# Looking for a GUI application to enter linux commands

Tags: linux, command-line, gui, user-interface

I am looking for a GUI console where I can enter linux commands in an entry widget and the result will be output in a text area widget. Is there is such software available?

A console programs like gnome-terminal or xterm, the screen keeps scrolling with every new command, and I find this annoying specially when the result has a few dozen lines.

I would like to visualize the command and the result at the same time, alike a browser entering a web address in the address bar and obtaining the website as a result.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not perfect but I made an interface to your specifications using [gtkdialog](http://code.google.com/p/gtkdialog/) (not to be confused with [GtkDialog](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkDialog.html)).

It's just a script (depends on *gtkdialog*), `chmod +x` and run. [Download here](http://goo.gl/w04ZOr).

[image: OneTerm]

Comment: Thanks for the script, it works as expected. One note though gtkdialog needs to be compile with vte support to work. For example in Archlinux the gtkdialog in the AUR packages should be used instead of the official repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Terminal emulators like `gnome-terminal` and `xfce4-terminal` both offer options to disable "Scroll on output" in their preferences.

Whenever a command is run with this disabled, you can scroll back up and any new lines will not cause the terminal emulator to go to the last output line.

Also, if you are running a command which isn't interactive, you can run `command | less` to read the output with `less`.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be too hard to roll your own web interface to the unix command line: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/executing-linuxunix-commands-from-web-page-part-i.html

Or you could try something like tmux: http://tmux.sourceforge.net/ which I think allows you to send the output of command in one pane to another pane: http://ricochen.wordpress.com/2011/11/14/tmux-techniques-by-example/